# Problems suspending notebook

Tags: boot, laptop, shutdown, power-management, suspend

I have problems suspending and shutting down Lenovo G560.

Suspend problem: after suspending neither power indicator, nor power button begin to blink. Capslock and Numlock leds don't turn off after I hear "tsk" sound(probably HDD turning off). Pressing buttons(power button as well) doesn't resume OS.

Shut down/rebooting: Windows, Linux, boot order, bios setting everything freezes for 1-3 seconds, then shuts down/reboots.
Linux shows message

```
Failed to finalize file systems, DM devices, ignoring
```

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but these happened after installing Hackintosh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing CMOS battery was enough to fix the issue.

Comment: You might want to check Lenovo for BIOS/driver updates.  An update might fix the issue permanently.